# Booting Gentoo on LVM inside LUKS with gpg encrypted keyfile

Tags: linux, boot, gentoo, lvm, luks

I'm trying to install Gentoo on LVM logical volume inside LUKS container encrypted with key file encrypted by GPG with passphrase. Everything was going smoothly until I tried to boot. I'm building the kernel and initramfs with genkernel:

```
genkernel --lvm --luks --install --menuconfig --busybox all
```

and booting it with GRUB2. So after I start the kernel I get the information that my key file gets found, but in the next line I get “Failed to open LUKS device...” and than comes a kernel panic. Any idea what to do?

Kernel config - http://pastebin.com/YR7TfaVm

GRUB2 menuentry:

```
menuentry 'Gentoo'{
root='hd1,gpt1'
linux /kernel-genkernel-x86_64-3.17.7-gentoo initrd=/dev/ram0 crypt_root=/dev/disk/by-partuuid/PARTUUID_OF_LUKS_CONTAINTER_PARTION dolvm real_root=/dev/mapper/vg1-root rootfstype=ext4 real_init=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd root_keydev=/dev/disk/by-partuuid/PARTUUID_OF_MY_PENDRIVE_WITH_KEY root_key=luks-key.gpg
initrd /initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-3.17.7-gentoo
echo "initing..."
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this was cross posted and has an answer at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183666/booting-gentoo-on-lvm-inside-luks-with-gpg-encrypted-keyfile

Answer (score 0):

Genkernel uses gpg v.1; you're probably doing something that needs gpg v.2, which requires pinentry and the like. Consider using luks itself to encrypt the keyfile: [dm-crypt+luks: Can I have a separate header without storing it on the luks encrypted device?](https://superuser.com/questions/823922/dm-cryptluks-can-i-have-a-separate-header-without-storing-it-on-the-luks-encry)